# How do I save date/time in some other timezone

Tags: javascript, date

I need to save a Date: February 16th, 2017 5PM HST.

The database (Parse) only accepts JS Date. And, my system timezone is IST.
JS Date does not have the ability to save in a different timezone.

To overcome this, I save three variables. Date (Calculated, calculation explained below), Timezone Offset, Timezone

Date is converted using `moment.tz(DateObject, Timezone)`.

But, calling the toDate() function, seems to change it back to IST.

On further examination, I found a `_d` key to the Moment object, which seems to have the converted datetime in IST.

But, I seem to cannot get it to work.

Any hints would be helpful.

Comment: What do you mean by "save in a different timezone"? Timezone is a presentation-layer concern. `01:00+00:00` and `02:00-01:00` are the same _time_, presented differently. The point in time is represented using a large integer (the _timestamp_), and this timestamp is the thing you should save. When you load this timestamp and want to use it again: you can _present_ it from the perspective of any zone you choose.

Comment: Can you post the code snippet you have coded?

Comment: @Birchlabs I cannot save a timestamp as the Parse Server only accepts a JS Date.  "save in a different timezone", this means that I may need to save the date which I select according to say, HST or PST. In a broader scope, this implies, that it wont be saved in 5 IST and show the user a date according to their timezone. I need to store 5 HST. Let me know, if I make sense.

Comment: you say that `toDate()` _seems_ to change the time back to IST… please understand that this is only presentation-layer. If you ask the Date object for its underlying timestamp (`myDate.getTime()`), you'll see the actual data that it's based on. but if you _pretty print_ it, it will try to present it in your own locale. I don't expect that there is anything you can do to make JS Date _present_ in a timezone (other than GMT/UTC/local), but I assure you that (assuming your server relies on the Date's `getTime()` instead of its pretty-print), it is fine to send the Date even if it presents badly.

Comment: @ankitjain11—Date objects are based on a UTC time value, they do not have a time zone. The host timezone may be used when creating a Date, when formatting as a string for output and for the non–UTC methods. The Date itself is effectively UTC, always.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you mean by "save in a different timezone"? Timezone is a presentation-layer concern. `01:00+00:00` and `02:00-01:00` are the same time, presented differently. The point in time is represented using a large integer (the timestamp), and this timestamp is the thing you should save.

When you load this timestamp and want to use it again: you can present it from the perspective of any zone you choose.

```
//-- parsing the user input...

// parse HST (Honolulu Standard Time) date-time
var inputTime = moment.tz("February 16th, 2017 5PM", "MMMM Do, YYYY hA", "Pacific/Honolulu");

// in case you want to double-check that it parsed correctly
var inputTimePrettyPrinted = inputTime.format(); // "2017-02-16T17:00:00-10:00"

// grab timestamp
var timestamp = +inputTime;

//-- presenting the stored timestamp in Indian Standard Time...

// install a timezone definition for Indian Standard Time
moment.tz.add("Asia/Calcutta|HMT BURT IST IST|-5R.k -6u -5u -6u|01232|-18LFR.k 1unn.k HB0 7zX0");
moment.tz.link("Asia/Calcutta|Asia/Kolkata");

var timePresentedInIndianTime = moment(timestamp).tz("Asia/Calcutta");

var indianTimePrettyPrinted = timePresentedInIndianTime.format(); // "2017-02-17T08:30:00+05:30"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
var UTC = new Date();
var UTC = UTC.getTime() // Get UTC Timestamp

var IST = new Date(date); // Clone UTC Timestamp
IST.setHours(IST.getHours() + 5); // set Hours to 5 hours later
IST.setMinutes(IST.getMinutes() + 30); // set Minutes to be 30 minutes later

var EST = new Date(date); // Clone date
EST.setHours(EST.getHours() - 4); // set EST to be 4 hour earlier
```

You can change according to your need.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use moment tz to add to HST

```
var now = new Date();
moment.tz.add('HST|HST|a0|0|');
console.clear();
var converted = moment(now).tz("HST").format();
console.log(now);

console.log(converted);
```

Here is the [jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/f7xmbkm5/)

Check console.log for the answer.

```
Fri Feb 17 2017 18:24:49 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) //IST time
2017-02-17T02:54:49-10:00 // HST Time
```